# Apache Load Balancer 2.4 not decreasing busy

Tags: windows, apache, load-balancing

i have setup a simple loadbalancer using Apacher 2.4 for 2 tomcat servers. i have noticed that the BUSY column in the balancer-manager page never decreases and keep increasing until both of them reach around 200, the performance will be very sluggish.

[image: balancer-manager web frontend]

i cannot find any documentation detailing about the balancer-manager frontend but i guessing the BUSY column is referring to the number of open connections to the balancer members. is that right?

does my apache LB doesnt close idles connection and keep opening new one until it exhausted the resources.

[image: My balancers setup]

Please guide me on this. i have to keep restarting apache services every week in order to reset the BUSY column and make the LB smooth again.

Server running on Windows 2003 + Apache 2.4.4

Comment: How are your Tomcat configured?  What is the value of maxThreads have you set on the Connector?  You Tomcat might be overloaded.  You can view how many connections you have, form Tomcat's perspective, by looking at the `currentThreadCount` and `currentThreadsBusy` using JMX, in section `Catalina:type=ThreadPool,name="SOMENAME"`.  Note that the section name will vary in your setup.

Comment: those Tomcat are from 3rd party vendor... since the system is basically an old system and we dont have support anymore ( the webcache is dont working as expected ).. this is a temporary solution on our side to provide LoadBalancer.

Comment: when the Busyness is too high, accessing the system directly without using LB is fast..thus why i suspect it is the Apache config problem.

Comment: ok.  Then you can monitor apache workers by activating `/server-status` (mod_status).  Be careful, ensure you configure it to respond only to internal IPs, you would not want the Internet to see that.  This will show you the threads, basic performance, ...  It will also show you what each thread is doing.  Ex. responding to query ?????, keep alive, ...  You might see something there.

Comment: ok tq.. ill updated the result in here later..

Comment: it seems all server-status is showing are the connections between LB ( apache ) and the clients.. not the connections between LB (apache) and the backend(tomcat).. there is nothing unusual on the server-status.. but on the balancer-manager, the BUSY keep increasing

Comment: Yes but usually, a connection to the back entails a connection from the front.  So the worker is busy, maintaining the connection to the backend open.  If not, then it most probably is the firewall between the LB and Tomcat maintaining the connections artificially up.  If Tomcat sees 100 connections from the Apache, yet the Apache claims only to have - for example - 25, then something in the middle is causing this.